# How to get Image source in Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware

Tags: facebook, image, tiki-wiki

I have trouble with image source of an article thumbnail in Tiki. I am getting image path with ***"*http://www.droit-inc.com/article_image.php?image_type=article&id=10348*"*** but I want root directory path of it. Because when I am passing this url via Facebook share button, then it's not working for me. I need root path for the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add &.jpg at the end of the link like this and Facebook will recognize it:
Test http://www.droit-inc.com/article_image.php?image_type=article&id=10348&.jpg